# How to get different outcomes of two variables being different percentage to eachother

Tags: php, percentage

I have a database with different events which includes the max number of participants
I have a page that shows people what events we have, and with a link to the inscripe form.
The inscriptions of all events come together in the same table with a column of what event they inscriped in. ATM it shows how many places there are and how many people have subscribed already. It also blocks new inscriptions if the number of inscriptions is equal to the max number of participants. This looks as follows:

```
           <h2 class="title">
            <?php 
                           //display eventname
              $sql = "SELECT eventname FROM events WHERE id=1";    
              $data = $conn->query($sql);
              if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
                while($event = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo $event["eventname"];
                  $eventname = $event["eventname"];
                }
              } 
            ?> 
           </h2>

           <h2 style="color:red;"> 
              <?php 
                               //display registered participants
                $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eventregistrations WHERE eventname='$eventname'"); 
                $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $result = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
                echo $result[0].'/'; 
                $numberparticipants = $result[0];

                          // display max participants
                $sql = "SELECT maxparticipants FROM events WHERE id=1";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo $row["maxparticipants"];
                    $maxparticipants = $row["maxparticipants"];
                   }
                 } 
              ?> 
            </h2>
```

$numberparticipants and $maxparticipants are used later to alter the link to the inscripeform

What I want to achieve is that the page doesn't show exactly the number, but just the idea of how full the event is. Something like

```
      if ($numberparticipants < 80% of $maxparticipants) {
      echo 'free places';
      } else if ($numberparticipants BETWEEN 80% of $maxparticipants AND $maxparticipants ) {
      echo 'almost full';
      } else {
      echo 'full';
      }
```

Thx
Beau-Jay

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Don’t know how to properly do the percentage math in PHP? Well 80% of something, is that something multiplied by `.8`

Comment: `BETWEEN` does not exist as a comparison operator in PHP. But you don’t need it here anyway, because the first part of that condition was already covered, by your initial IF. If the value was < 80% in there, then it is not going to be < 80% in the ELSE branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something like

```
$eightyPercent = intval(0.8 * $maxparticipants);
if($eightyPercent < $numberparticipants && $numberparticipants < $maxparticipants){
      echo 'almost full';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registrations WHERE eventname='$eventname'"); 
            $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $result = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
            $numberparticipants = $result[0];
            $sql = "SELECT maxparticipants FROM events WHERE id=1";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $maxparticipants = $row["maxparticipants"];}}
            $p80maxparticipants = ($maxparticipants *0.8);
            
            if ($numberparticipants < $p80maxparticipants) {
                echo 'Open for inscription';
            }else if ($numberparticipants >= $p80maxparticipants && $numberparticipants < $maxparticipants) {
                echo 'allmost full';
            }else if ($numberparticipants == $maxparticipants) {
                echo 'Volzet';
            }else{
                echo 'error';
            }
```

Comment: The `$numberparticipants >= $p80maxparticipants &&` part is superfluous. The initial `if` checked whether `$numberparticipants < $p80maxparticipants` was the case already, so in the following `else if` nothing but `$numberparticipants >= $p80maxparticipants` _can_ be the case.